# iterate through VBA collection as while adding to it

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to iterate though a collection as i build it, the reason for this is i have a table consisting of three columns:
ID, ParentID, CategoryName

where a record in the table can be a "child" of another category by filling in the ParentID column.

as part of a delete function on a form I need to check if the selected item:
A) has any children categories
B) has any products that belong to that category
C) any of the children categories have and products in them

however the code sample I have made doesn't do what I would expect, I tried using a For, Next loop, but this only worked with the collection as it was when I started the loop, adding to it in the loop just gets ignored.

then I tried using a variable for an index and incrementing it until I exceed the list count. however this then throws an error of 3420 - "Object invalid or no longer set"

if anyone can help me either help me understand why i am getting this error or a better way to do this i would appreciate it.

the end result is i need a list containing the category ID and all child ID's

my code sample is:

```
Dim cat_index As Integer
Dim cat_list As New Collection

cat_list.Add ListCategories.Column(0) 'add top category id to list

cat_index = 1

Dim cat_rst As DAO.Recordset 'recordset to hold search results

Do Until cat_index > cat_list.Count
    MsgBox "Debug:" & vbCrLf & "cat_id:" & cat_id & vbCrLf & "cat_index:" & cat_index & vbCrLf & "cat_list.Count:" & cat_list.Count 'fault finding
    cat_id = cat_list.Item(cat_index)
    Set cat_rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM Categories WHERE ParentID = " & cat_id & ";")
    If cat_rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Do Until cat_rst.EOF 'loop until end of records
            MsgBox cat_rst![ID]
            cat_list.Add cat_rst![ID]
            cat_rst.MoveNext
        Loop
        cat_rst.Close
    End If
    cat_index = cat_index + 1
Loop
```

P.S. if it makes any difference I'm using access 2013

Edit:
to clarify I have a total of three tables that would matter to this function:
Categories has ID, ParentID, CategoryName
Products has ID, Name
Product_Categories has ProductID, CategoryID

where only the first two tables have a primary key (the ID column), this means I use the first two tables to define the categories and the products, and the third table to put the products in categories, this way a product can be in multiple categories.

Comment: I think I'm lost... you say 'as part of a delete function...', but I see your code is ADDING more items to the collection? And what does 'ListCategories' contain? And your code will possibly add duplicates?

Comment: its adding to that collection as i need a complete list of all sub categories first, which i then want touse to make a list of all products to belong to any of them, and then offer the option to remove all of these table entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered strange results when trying to use a 'Collection' (even though item count was increasing, was unable to reference). So, I converted the code to use a Dictionary.

Just for clarification about your A, B, C 'rules', it appears you need more code to satisfy all three. But I don't know what you mean by 'Products'? How are they related / defined?

```
Private Sub cmdArray_Click()
Dim cat_index   As Integer
Dim cat_List    As Dictionary
Dim cat_id      As Integer
Dim strSQL      As String
Dim cat_rst     As DAO.recordSet    'recordset to hold search results

    Set cat_List = New Dictionary
    'Tabe contains:  ID, ParentID, CategoryName

    cat_List.add CStr(ListCategories.Column(0)), ListCategories.Column(0)
    Debug.Print "Added Value of: " & ListCategories.Column(0)
    Debug.Print "cat_List contains: " & cat_List.Count & " entries"

    cat_index = 0           ' Relative to zero

    Do              'Do Until cat_index > cat_List.Count
        cat_id = cat_List.Items(cat_index)

        Debug.Print "cat_id: " & vbTab & cat_id & vbTab & "cat_index: " & vbTab & cat_index & vbTab & "cat_list.Count: " & vbTab & cat_List.Count  'fault finding
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE ParentID = " & cat_id & ";"
        Set cat_rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        If Not cat_rst.EOF Then
            Do Until cat_rst.EOF        'loop until end of records
                Debug.Print "    Found ID: " & cat_rst![ID] & vbTab & "Parent: " & cat_rst!ParentID & vbTab & "CategoryName: " & cat_rst!CategoryName
                cat_List.add cat_rst![ID], CStr(cat_rst![ID])
                cat_rst.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            Debug.Print "    No records found for: " & cat_id
        End If
        cat_rst.Close

        cat_index = cat_index + 1

        If cat_index >= cat_List.Count Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was unaware of the dictionary object until now. This works perfectly although to make it work with my version of access i had to add a reference to the microsoft scripting runtime and use Scripting.Dictionary instead.